# How to process data with the DRF serializer

Tags: django

How can I convert time data (in seconds) to HH:MM:SS form in the DRF serializer?
There is a model and a serializer like this.

Model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,
                                related_name='entries',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name='entries',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.project.name, self.created_at)
```

Serializer

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True)
    project_post = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Project.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    hms = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_date):
        validated_date['project'] = validated_date.get('project_post', None)
        if validated_date['project'] is None:
            raise serializer.ValidationError("project")
        del validated_date['project_post']
        return Entry.objects.create(**validated_date)
```

In the case of JavaScript, I was able to convert it with the following code, but how do I do it with the DRF Serializer?

```
const time = this.state.time + 1;
const hours = parseInt(time / 60 / 60, 10);
const minutes = parseInt(time / 60 % 60, 10);
const seconds = parseInt(time % 60, 10);
this.setState({
    hours: this.toText(hours),
    minutes: this.toText(minutes),
    seconds: this.toText(seconds),
    time: time
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If request data is in seconds(ex: 1675716401) as below, then it should be doable with python `datetime` library, if not please specify the format in which datetime is provided and re-format it using strftime [https://strftime.org][1]

```
 from datetime import datetime
    datetime.fromtimestamp(1675716401).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

In `EntrySerializer` you can add method as below with needed format

```
def get_hms(hms):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(hms).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Time I have used is Epoch time, so converting exact 84 seconds deosnt make much sense, If you are aware of the date then use `relativedelta` to adjust time and it mainly depend on how the input you get.

Below is sample to add seconds to current time

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now() + relativedelta(seconds=90)
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 22, 14, 29, 56, 758793)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried that method, but 84 seconds should be converted to 00:01:24, but for some reason it is 09:01:24.
What is the reason for this?